# A problem about diagonal lattice path

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

The problem I am facing is: Suppose we have a diagonal lattice path which is defined over a $x-y$ coordinate plane. We can go either from $(i,j)$ to $(i+1,j+1)$ or from $(i,j)$ to $(i+1,j-1)$. Then the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ is ${m\choose\frac{m-n}{2}}$. Now show that the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,3)$ that go below $y=-1$ is ${n\choose\frac{n+7}{2}}$.

I have no idea how the formula is obtained. Any help please?

Comment: Reflect the left prefix up to and including the first down step to $y=-2$ about $y=-2$. Then the image starts at $(0,-4)$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Sorry but I don't get your point. Would you like to be more specific? My English is not very well......

Comment: Have you read the answers in the question linked above your question? It goes into all the necessary details.